# Every field has exactly 2 ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I want to prove that every field has exactly 2 ideals.

I know that the two ideals are $0$ and the whole set itself. That is clear to me. I am a little unsure how to prove it though.

Comment: If it's not the zero ideal, it contains a nonzero number. In a field, every nonzero number is ...

Comment: Hmm I can see how the whole set is an ideal but I am still unsure of zero. Why does an ideal have at least the zero element?